# How to upload nifti images

Tags: python, nifti

I have a folder with files that have the format **.nii.gz.** How can I upload these images in Python? Should I create a for loop ? Any help please

Answer (score 0):

you can use this link to get how import your data:

http://www.jarrodmillman.com/rcsds/lectures/loading_nifti_images.html

Comment: Thank you!!! I have already done this part. But i want to upload a lot of niftii images, not only one at a time. Do you have any recommendation?

Comment: I am not sure about how looks like your dataset, but this link also describe a lot about how working with this type of data:https://neuraldatascience.io/8-mri/nifti.html